# Standard Contact Form to add on my website

Tags: php, contact-form

I want to know if there are any recognised and secure contact form scripts i can embed on my webpage and customise the style.

If any one can help provide me with links, resources, etc.

PHP Please. Not Wordpress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there you go:

- http://wufoo.com/gallery/templates/forms/contact-form/
- http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/premium-php-contact-forms/
- http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/custom-php-contact-forms/
- http://sixrevisions.com/wordpress/free-contact-form-plugins/
- http://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-create-contact-form-html.html
- http://www.freecontactform.com/html_form.php
- http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php
- http://phpeasystep.com/phptu/8.html
- http://www.kirupa.com/web/php_contact_form.htm

Too many ? Yeah because you didn't specify for what you need it, PHP, Wordpress, HTML, .... consider that the next time so the answers could be more precise ;)

EDIT: I have added some more ;-)